# Динамический upload_to в Django, отдельный для каждого пользователя

Tags: django-orm, python, upload, django

Здравствуйте! Есть модель, с полями FileField и ImageField, и полем

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Необходимо чтобы upload_to формировался из id пользователя(и желательно еще из произвольной строки, но это не обязательно).

Например:

**1) вариант:**

"321/userfile.png"

"321/doc1.txt"

**2) вариант:**

"321/avatars/userfile.png"

"321/documents/doc1.txt"

Я пробовал передавать в upload_to функцию:

```
def make_upload_path(self, filename):
    return str(self.user.id)
```

Но это работает только в случае если я определяю эту функцию до всех полей, ну и я не могу для разных полей определить разные пути(как во втором примере).

Как можно реализовать такое поведение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, если передавать в upload_to какой-то callable - это совсем не обязательно должен быть метод модели, я обычно использую отдельные функции (первым аргументом туда приходит объект, а уж self этот аргумент называется или instance - не так важно. Тогда проблема с необходимостью втыкать метод перед полями модели отпадает.

Во-вторых, метапрограммирование рулит. Функцию для передачи в upload_to можно не задавать явно, а генерировать другой функцией, примерно так же, как работают декораторы. Получится что-то типа:

```
def get_upload_to(prefix):
    def _tmp(instance, filename):
        return os.path.join(instance.pk, prefix, filename)
    return _tmp

avatar = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_to('avatars'))
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вынес функцию за класс модели, заменил instance.pk на instance.user_id и все работает как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое решение, по типу твоего make_upload_path используешь функцию

```
def get_file_path(obj, filename):
if hasattr(obj, 'upload_dir'):
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), extension)
    return os.path.join(obj.upload_dir, filename)
else:
    raise AttributeError("%s does not have 'upload_dir' attribute" % obj.__class__.__name__)
```

а в каждой модели в свою очередь прописываешь свойство типа:

```
    @property
def upload_dir(self):
    return "product_pictures"
```

Таким образом у тебя будут уникальные имена файлов и для каждой модели своя директория куда файлы будут складываться. Ну и если надо там модифицируй чуток четвертую строку чтоб id юзера в имя попадал. А чтоб получить уникальный путь для каждого поля в пределах одной модели, дублируй функцию или привяжись к расширению файла и по условию расширь путь, например.

Comment: Решение ваше понял, но оно не совсем мне подходит. Спасибо за ответ.